# What are the minimal MySQL grants for the debian-sys-maint user?

Tags: mysql, security, permissions, debian

What are the minimal privileges that `debian-sys-maint@localhost` needs for the mysql service to work correctly?

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/480890) on ServerFault suggests granting `RELOAD` only, but this is incorrect, as it prevents the mysql service from stopping or starting properly.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to protect you MySQL server from.

To be able to automatically manage the MySQL db server, Debian has added the account `debian-sys-maint@localhost`.  That account is used to start, stop and do some other maintenance on the database without any user is needed to type in an administrator password.  That might look frighting at first, but actually are not, as long as you have the server protected from unauthorized use.

The `debian-sys-maint@localhost` user are only accessible from the local machine through `localhost`, so you can't connect to MySQL as that user unless you already are logged in on the server machine. 
As the password for that MySQL account is only readable by the administrator account `root`, the attacker need to be `root` to be able to read and use it to access this Debian acccount.

```
$ ls -l /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
-rw------- 1 root root 666 sep 14  2010 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

So, when the privileges for `debian-sys-maint@localhost` is of any real concern, you have a much worse problems with an unauthorized user with root access on your server. The access to the MySQL db is your least concern then.

Also notice that if an unauthorized user has access to the computer as `root`, there are nothing you can do to stop them from restarting MySQL with all authorization code in MySQL deactivated. With that, they have access to everything, like adding a new Administration account and then restart the MySQL server with authorization activated again. And you wouldn't noticed a thing, at first...

So no, this isn't as a large security problem as it might look at first sight.  So no, one doesn't need to change this from the access already given by Debian.

Comment: This is useful background for someone unfamiliar with how the `debian-sys-maint` user works, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well, it gives you the minimum needed grants. As suggested, you need more then just `RELOAD`.  The maintainer user needs all priv.  And yes, I also explain why that isn't a problem, so people wouldn't experiment with it when they don't need too. Not for any security reasons at least.

Comment: To clarify: the answer I'm looking for is something like: "The user needs privilege X to do A, privilege Y to do B, and privilege Z to C.  If you want to do D you also need privilege W."  Minimal privileges are desirable e.g. to protect against malfunctioning scripts or possible privilege escalation.  I understand that the user needs certain administrative privileges but it probably doesn't need to be able to read/write to tables containing customer data.

Comment: Ok. On top of my mind, It needs to create and remove databases and tables, to add and remove users and it needs to be able to stop the server.
That is what I have read in all the discussion about the subject. And yes, the `debian-sys-maint` users passwords are protected so only root user knows it.
If one get root access, one don't need the `debian-sys-maint` user to access all databases. That can easily be done by restart the MySQL database without any authentification activated to create a new admin user, then restart the MySQL server like nothing has happen.